# Appeal on overpunishment for exceeding word count was denied – how to proceed?

Tags: coursework, legal-issues, administration

I made an academic appeal over the marking of an essay, which was 13 words over the word limit.  The mark on the word-count section was unexpected, but was not consistent with the formal university word-limit marking rubric. (I cannot change the essay anymore.) Unexpectedly, my appeal was denied.

How should I further advance the appeal?
Here is what I considered so far:

1. Rely on independent student advocate, found by internal university contact. The issue with this is that I don’t know whether they play their role effectively. My first appeal was already denied. And before marking academic appeal, I did request for independent student advocate to be involved and witness debate of academic appeals process.
2. Approach an ombudsman and independent student advocate to invite them observe the entire process of complaints to the university registrar (invitation goes before arrival of formal approach, so there are witnesses to breakdowns in procedures)? This seems workable solution, and is an option I believe I can trust.
3. Consult the family lawyer to engage in challenges and observe the review process to make sure no more maladministration.
4. Perhaps a combination of 2 and 3? This may be too aggressive, but seems to have a higher chance of success than 2 **or** 3.

Is my thinking sound? Is there a better way I haven’t thought of?

Details on word count inconsistency are as follows......
a/ There are 5 gradated sections for word count limits.  There is no hard public published specification on when you transition from one gradated section to another.  There is no published specification that suggests that if 5 (or 10 or 15)% over word limit then you lose marks.  The marking rubric is vague and does not specify what percentage over word limits, transition you from one gradated marking section to the next one down. 
It is at the marker's discretion

b/ My essay had a word limit of 2500 words.  My submitted essay had a word count of 2513 words, or 13 words (0.5 %) over the word limit. From my understanding based on experience from submitting previous essays within this department and university system, it should have gotten in the top section (because it was within the previous experience of applied margin of errors before mark degradation), or one down from the top gradated section.  The mark I got for the word count section was the 2nd section from the bottom.

c/ I did email the instructor (before essay deadline) for guidance on when word count limits transition from one formal marking section to another, eg 5% or 10% etc.  The instructor never replied to this query.

d/ the word limits was only for the main body of the essay only -where the substantive argument is.  Word count does not include title, references, bibliography, footnotes.

e/ the essay word count was not changed after first formal deadline.  It was the same word count at the time of submission of first formal deadline, as it was at the time of academic appeals denial.

Would you like any other details?

Comment: My instructor viewed a draft 400 words over the word limit on the wednesday before the essay deadline - I was able to reduce this to 13 words(over the word limit)by the time of essay deadline submission.  I cannot further reduce essay length word count after essay deadline submission......its a different set of circumstances to change the "assignment" outside the rules of the game.  For our university, to be able to change the "assignment" after the first formal assignment deadline, you need to apply for "special consideration" - I didn't qualify for this at the time

Comment: My instructor got the roughly 400 words (over word limit) draft essay by email on the wednesday (3 days before deadline)..... so there is a record of that. Neither the instructor nor I, have anything but respectful relations with each other

Comment: Question reopened and comments purged (since all should be addressed; if not, repost). @Anti-Tao: Please check whether everything is correct. Also, can you please [edit] your question to specify how bad your grade was (in comparison to what you consider the fair grading) and what impact this has on your studies? This may allow us to give better answers.

Comment: What's the word limit order of magnitude? Are abstract and title, as well as footnotes included in the word limit? You need to find inconsistency or inaccuracy in description to battle this, or unreasonable difficulties in computing the word count in your document (which may be the case if any of the above was difficult to estimate) or I see little recourse for you if the word limit was known beforehand. Even if myself I would consider a hard word limit ridiculous, it was part of the task.

Comment: The question is still missing details on what the penalty given was and what the official guidelines stated. The fact that the essay was originally much longer and was later cut down after turning it in (as was mentioned by OP in a comment) also seems potentially relevant, depending on what the official guidelines state.

Comment: Proceeding with a lawyer seems to be the best option because you are in a dispute with the rules. Arguing within the university system won't work well because the rules are going to be upheld. The core of the argument is essentially that sticking rigorously to the rules is unreasonable, and that has to be argued outside of the university system where the university will be forced to defend the reasons for having the rules and enforcing these rules so strictly. They then cannot engage in a circular argument involving those same rules.

Comment: With the added details, it certainly seems harsh to move that far for such a small amount in excess (though how you could ever expect to be placed in the top one is beyond me). The details about changing word count is still missing (the comment was deleted along with the rest, so I can't see it, but I recall you mentioned originally submitting something 400 words too long).

Comment: @TobiasKildetoft: I undeleted those comments. If you can, please edit whatever part you consider relevant into the question.

Comment: @Wrzlprmft Actually, on re-reading them I see that I misremembered them. Having sent a too long draft ahead of time is probably not relevant anyway).

Comment: It is hard to be sympathetic, actually. You seem to have made a lot of assumptions. You seem to be overly judgmental of the actions of others and not accepting your own errors. It is easy enough, today, to check your word count. It only takes a few moments and minimal effort. You are suggesting bringing in lawyers for what is, in essence, a request for special treatment. My advice is to swallow this and do better in future.

Comment: **What was the actual penalty?** "Second section of the bottom" doesn't tell us how severe the actual penalty was.

Comment: @JeffE vague application of marking rubric - all students get is a total overall mark (based up on a vague formula combining all sections of the grading rubric), not individual marks per section - at least in this assignment

Comment: Let me try again: How much higher would your grade have been without the penalty for going over the word limit?  10 points out of 100?  Two letter grades?  If you can't give a precise answer, then why are you complaining about this _specific_ penalty?

Comment: There are other issues with the marking of the paper, based on the marker's comments in the paper - hard to convey here,  without actually seeing the comments in context of the relevant sections of the paper.  I am attempting to use the clear word count issue to initiate at least a partial remarking, but hopefully a full remarking.  There have been observations by other individuals, which "I" took to indicate the paper was grossly under-marked (for whatever reason) - not an accusation against the instructors. I need clarification of those comments and marks, due my great efforts in writing

Comment: @JeffE - also a principle at stake here for me. I am sick of just accepting poor treatment, when there are proper ways of doing things.  As for marks, it is unclear how much more a partial remarking on word count would add - due to vagueness of marking rubric.  Or how much more a full remarking by a independent impartial competent marker would add, due to vaguness of comments and marking rubric.  I am rather at the end of my tether, and feel like I need to make a stand. There is a strong emotional element in response to being constantly pushed, and I am taking this opportunity to push back.

Comment: Also, finally, I see an opportunity to push back, that I have confidence in that I have good chances of success in.  I haven't had this assessment of chances of winning before.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your post sets out details of the substantive matters in your case, but it does not give any information on the adjudication rules and the avenues for appeal in the rules.  You have already appealed to the university, and this failed.  You refer to this as your "first appeal", but you have not made clear whether there are any other steps of appeal allowed in the process.  If there is another step of appeal allowed in the rules then you may avail yourself of this; if not, then that is the end of the (internal) adjudication process.  Thus, the first thing you need to do, if you are interested in pursuing this, is to read the university process for appeals of marks, and see if you have exhausted the internal appeal process.

If you decide to contact a student advocate, ombudsman, or lawyer, their first step will be to find out what has happened so far, and whether you have any additional right of appeal within the university rules.  A paid lawyer will happily attend meetings, hearings, etc., with you, but that will be very expensive.  For a student advocate or ombudsman, they will make their own decisions on what, if any, actions they wish to take to mediate the matter, and they would be unlikely to agree to attend the entire process.  The substantive complaint you have sounds weak to me, and presumes various things that are not requirements by the university.  Moreover, if the appeal process is already exhausted then you unlikely even to get to an assessment on the merits (since that has presumably already been done).  If there is no further right of appeal, the most likely outcome is that the university will write to you (or your lawyer, ombudsman, etc.) stating that the appeal process has already occurred and is now concluded.

Answer (score 12):

Accept it and move on.  Consider:

1. You had a clear rule for the word count
2. You violated that rule
3. You appealed and were denied

And that's it.  Engaging in other extreme forms of behavior, such as trying to involve a lawyer (!), will surely sour the attitude of everyone involved toward you.

To address one point specifically, when you didn't hear back from the professor about word count rules, you should probably have defaulted to following the rules to the letter.  I personally try to always respond to the emails I get, but I admit I vastly deprioritize emails that are asking me things with clear answers already available - such as a word count limit.

Answer (score 9):

Your best course of action is going to be to accept things and move on.

Unless the marks you've lost on this essay make the difference between getting your degree or not, the damage to your reputation incurred by any of your options will significantly outweigh the gains.